# How to hold a tag in <head> selector only in main page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, data-structures, react-router

I have a `structureData.js` file that has a data structure. In the main file inside the `<head>`I have

```
<script type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: structureData }}></script>
```

And everything looks fine - in developer tools it's displayed. The point is, I would like to hold this `<script>` tag only in the main site (e.g `www.example.com`) but when user sees e.g. `www.example.com/service` - this tag should be removed. Is it possible to implement it to make that `structureData script` removed in every subpage (I use ReactRouter)? I'd be very grateful for help

Comment: Yes? You should be having specific components (views) displayed on different pages, controlled by the router. What have you tried?

Comment: I mean, I don't know how to render that `script` in return function to be placed in <head> tag